# Pandas GUI on Kaggle: ContextualVersionConflict: (..... {'matplotlib'})

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandasgui

On Kaggle Notebook I tried to install and run `pandasgui` but running into following error. I have seen others using Kaggle that they did not face issues or I think so (https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/getting-started/193116). Also, one more question: is `pandasgui` not that popular or powerful, so can we use it to import a dataframe with a few million rows?

```
!pip install pandasgui # installation was smooth with no issues. 

import pandas as pd
from pandasgui import show

# Example DataFrame
data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
    'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Show the DataFrame using PandasGUI
show(df)
```

present output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ContextualVersionConflict                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 2
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 from pandasgui import show
      4 # Example DataFrame
      5 data = {
      6     'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David'],
      7     'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
      8     'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago']
      9 }

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandasgui/__init__.py:3
      1 # Set version
      2 from pkg_resources import get_distribution
----> 3 __version__ = get_distribution('pandasgui').version
      5 # Logger config
      6 import logging

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:471, in get_distribution(dist)
    469     dist = Requirement.parse(dist)
    470 if isinstance(dist, Requirement):
--> 471     dist = get_provider(dist)
    472 if not isinstance(dist, Distribution):
    473     raise TypeError("Expected string, Requirement, or Distribution", dist)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:347, in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    345 """Return an IResourceProvider for the named module or requirement"""
    346 if isinstance(moduleOrReq, Requirement):
--> 347     return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
    348 try:
    349     module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:891, in WorkingSet.require(self, *requirements)
    882 def require(self, *requirements):
    883     """Ensure that distributions matching `requirements` are activated
    884 
    885     `requirements` must be a string or a (possibly-nested) sequence
   (...)
    889     included, even if they were already activated in this working set.
    890     """
--> 891     needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
    893     for dist in needed:
    894         self.add(dist)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:782, in WorkingSet.resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    779 if dist not in req:
    780     # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    781     dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 782     raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    784 # push the new requirements onto the stack
    785 new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]

ContextualVersionConflict: (pyparsing 3.1.0 (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pyparsing<3.1,>=2.3.1'), {'matplotlib'})
```